# How can I call a function within a website?

Tags: python, html

I've been looking at the source HTML for various websites, and it would make my life much easier if I could call functions from the website I'm accessing on will. I'm using Python, but please keep in mind I am somewhat of a novice.

Comment: You'd need the websites to make the "functions" available to external "callers", e.g by using some variant of `REST`.  If the websites don't do that, you'll need to get whatever data the websites make available (ideally in JSON form -- second best, XML -- worst of all, HTML, parsing it e.g with `BeautifulSoup`) and process that data yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to access someone else's website using Python, you'll need to look into something like Python's [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) and [`beautifulsoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

If you want to execute functions inside that website (that require Javascript), you'll need to use a Python browser emulator like [enter link description here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) which is [described here](http://koaning.github.io/html/scapingdynamicwebsites.html). Hope this helps! It's quite a complex question.

If you're looking to *create* a webpage that runs Python code, that's unreasonable, as all Python code in web development is run server-side, and you'll have to rely on something like Javascript for that.